# TypeError: firebaseApp.auth is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase authentication in my react application for sign-in users but I am getting error:-TypeError: firebaseApp.auth is not a function.
My Firebase. file is:-

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app"
import "firebase/auth"

const firebaseApp=firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket:process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID
})
export const auth=firebaseApp.auth()
export default firebaseApp
```

Please help me with that

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the SDK version 9 installed but use SDK version 8 syntax.

You have 2 options. Addopt the new SDK to use the old syntax with importing your firebase like this:

```js
import * as firebase from "firebase/compat/app"
import "firebase/compat/auth"

const firebaseApp=firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket:process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID
})
export const auth=firebaseApp.auth()
export default firebaseApp
```

or

use the new syntax:

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  //...
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth();
```

Comment: Thnx 2nd method solved my problem, but now it is showing a new error   
×
Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key).
createErrorInternal
C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/src/core/util/assert.ts:128

Comment: Can you show use the error. The `initializeApp` also has to be done with the new syntax. Everything changed with SDK 9. Maybe it's that.

Comment: I highly recommend not encouraging someone to use the compatibility library in SDK v9, even though it is present, it is considered deprecated (it will be removed in the next major) and should only be used to help someone migrate legacy code to the new SDK.

Comment: Did you check my updated answer? It shows how to initializeApp works properly. @samthecodingman that depends if he has a old project or starting a new one. From the question I could not see what case he has and for that gave him both options :)